# jQuery UI resizing helper

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this example http://jsfiddle.net/9gEGM/1/

Javascript:

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({
    handles: 'all',
    ghost: true,
    minHeight: 300,
    minWidth: 300
});
```

When box has {width: 300, height: 300} I make resize by vertical and it becomes

- Object {width: 300, height: 300}
- Object {width: 299, height: 300}
- Object {width: 298, height: 300}
- Object {width: 297, height: 300}
- ...

But my options { minHeight: 300, minWidth: 300} ?

I tested in Chrome and Firefox look on console [image: screenshot (console output)]

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me

maybe try using css

```
#resizable{
min-width: 300px;
min-height: 300px,
}
```